# How to get angular init function in JavaScript using angular.element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My controller name is `ViewPostOnThreadCntrl` and the id of the controller div is `ViewPostOnThreadCntr`. When I call `ng-init` function in JavaScript then the following error is displayed:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetPostReplyByThreadId' of undefined

View Code

```
<section class="trdsec" ng-controller="ViewPostOnThreadCntrl" id="ViewPostOnThreadCntrl" ng-cloak>
  <div ng-init="GetPostReplyByThreadId()">
  </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript
 angular.element(document.getElementById('#ViewPostOnThreadCntrl')).scope().GetPostReplyByThreadId();

Controller

```
app.controller("ViewPostOnThreadCntrl", function ($scope, angularService) {

    $scope.GetPostReplyByThreadId = function () {
        id = getUrlParameter('id');
        if (id != '' && id > 0) {
            var getData = angularService.GetPostReplyByThreadId(id);
            getData.then(function (InnerDetail) {
                $scope.InnerDetails = InnerDetail.data;
                if (InnerDetail.data.CategoryId < 1)
                {
                    window.location='/Home/Index'
                }
            }, function () {
            });
        }
        else
        {
            window.location='/Home/Index'
        }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
success: function (result) {
            isSuccess = result;
            if (result > 0) {
                angular.element('#ViewPostOnThreadCntrl').scope().GetPostReplyByThreadId();
                $(e).closest("form").find("#PostText").val("");
                if (ID == 0) {
                    alert("Post Replied successfully.");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Replied successfully.");
                }
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(ID > 0 ? "#div-" + ID + "" : ".footer").offset().top }, 2000);
                if (ID == 0)
                    $('#ShowDiv').css({ 'display': 'none' });
            }
            else {
                alert("Post Replied Unsuccessfully.");

            }

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Post Replied Unsuccessfully.");
        }

    });
```

Comment: when i use "angular.element('#ViewPostOnThreadCntrl').scope().GetPostReplyByThreadId();" then "Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/jqLite/nosel" error occur

Comment: Where is that JavaScript? Show your controller code in full.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your angular controller define a function as follows

```
$scope.GetPostReplyByThreadId = function(){

// your logic here...

}
```

delete angular.element(...) line of code

Comment: $scope.GetPostReplyByThreadId is already Define in Angular. Error At Line angular.element('#ViewPostOnThreadCntrl').scope().GetPostReplyByThreadId();   "Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/jqLite/nosel"; error occur

Comment: but When i use angular.element(document.getElementById('#ViewPostOnThreadCntrl')).scope().GetPostReplyByThreadId(); then following error occur "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetPostReplyByThreadId' of undefined"